# Access is denied, While calling JavaScript function in VBA script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vba

**VBA Script**
Code to make localhost server call with calling the function in webpage.
It can to load the webpage but raising error while executing this line

```
Call CurrentWindow.execScript("test()")

Sub test()
    Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim objElement As IHTMLElement
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy
    Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorerMedium
    sURL = "http://localhost:8080/test4.html"
    With oBrowser
        .Silent = True
        .navigate sURL
        .Visible = True
    End With
    Do While oBrowser.Busy Or oBrowser.readyState <> 4
       DoEvents
    Loop
    Set CurrentWindow = oBrowser.document.parentWindow
    Call CurrentWindow.execScript("test()")
End Sub
```

**Html and JavaScript**

```
<html ng-app="notesApp">
    <head><title>Hello AngularJS</title></head>
    <body ng-controller="test4Controller">
        <button ng-click = test() >clickme</button>
        <script src="include/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="include/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module('notesApp'[])
            .controller('test4Controller'['$scope',function($scope) {
                $scope.test  = function() {
                    console.log("called"); 
                }; 
            }]);
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

This is the error what i got.

[image]